# How do I generate nested XML for many to many relationship in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

The situation is there are courses and lecturers and they have a many to many relationship (1 course can have many lecturers, 1 lecturer can teach many courses)

The following XML repeats the course name:

```
SELECT
    C.COURSE_ID "@course_id"
    ,   C.COURSE_NAME "Course_Name"
    --get lecturer id(s) of the course
    ,   CL.LECTURER_ID  

    FROM 
    COURSE C LEFT JOIN COURSE_LECTURER CL ON C.COURSE_ID = CL.COURSE_ID
    --LEFT JOIN AS ALL COURSES DON'T HAVE LECTURERS COULD BE INNER :)
FOR XML PATH('Course'), ROOT('Program')
```

It gives me the following output (snippet):

```
<Course course_id="ISFND 1.1">
    <Course_Name>Relational Databases and SQL</Course_Name>
    <LECTURER_ID>ME123</LECTURER_ID>
  </Course>
  <Course course_id="ISFND 1.1">
    <Course_Name>Relational Databases and SQL</Course_Name>
    <LECTURER_ID>HS123</LECTURER_ID>
  </Course>
```

But the output I want is:

```
<Course course_id="ISFND 1.1">
        <Course_Name>Relational Databases and SQL</Course_Name>
        <LECTURER_ID>ME123</LECTURER_ID>
        <LECTURER_ID>HS123</LECTURER_ID>
      </Course>
```

I guess there is some problem in my sql for many to many may be I need to use IN or something like for each. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Course_Lecturer is the relationship table between course and lecturer as it is many to many relationship.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    C.COURSE_ID "@course_id"
    ,   C.COURSE_NAME "Course_Name"
    , (SELECT CL.LECTURER_ID
       FROM COURSE_LECTURER CL
       WHERE C.COURSE_ID = CL.COURSE_ID
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
FROM COURSE C
FOR XML PATH('Course'), ROOT('Program')
```